# How to get request cookies in Web API authorization attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-web-api

In .NET there are two `AuthorizeAttribute` classes. One defined in `System.Web.Http` namespace:

```
namespace System.Web.Http
{
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the authorization filter that verifies the request's System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class AuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute class.
        public AuthorizeAttribute();

        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the authorized roles.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The roles string.
        public string Roles { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets a unique identifier for this attribute.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A unique identifier for this attribute.
        public override object TypeId { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the authorized users.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The users string.
        public string Users { get; set; }

        // Summary:
        //     Processes requests that fail authorization.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   actionContext:
        //     The context.
        protected virtual void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Indicates whether the specified control is authorized.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   actionContext:
        //     The context.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the control is authorized; otherwise, false.
        protected virtual bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Calls when an action is being authorized.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   actionContext:
        //     The context.
        //
        // Exceptions:
        //   System.ArgumentNullException:
        //     The context parameter is null.
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext);
    }
}
```

Another defined in `System.Web.Mvc` namespace:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies that access to a controller or action method is restricted to users
    //     who meet the authorization requirement.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class AuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute class.
        public AuthorizeAttribute();

        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the user roles that are authorized to access the controller
        //     or action method.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The user roles that are authorized to access the controller or action method.
        public string Roles { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the unique identifier for this attribute.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The unique identifier for this attribute.
        public override object TypeId { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the users that are authorized to access the controller or action
        //     method.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The users that are authorized to access the controller or action method.
        public string Users { get; set; }

        // Summary:
        //     When overridden, provides an entry point for custom authorization checks.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   httpContext:
        //     The HTTP context, which encapsulates all HTTP-specific information about
        //     an individual HTTP request.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the user is authorized; otherwise, false.
        //
        // Exceptions:
        //   System.ArgumentNullException:
        //     The httpContext parameter is null.
        protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Processes HTTP requests that fail authorization.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   filterContext:
        //     Encapsulates the information for using System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.
        //     The filterContext object contains the controller, HTTP context, request context,
        //     action result, and route data.
        protected virtual void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Called when a process requests authorization.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   filterContext:
        //     The filter context, which encapsulates information for using System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.
        //
        // Exceptions:
        //   System.ArgumentNullException:
        //     The filterContext parameter is null.
        public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Called when the caching module requests authorization.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   httpContext:
        //     The HTTP context, which encapsulates all HTTP-specific information about
        //     an individual HTTP request.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A reference to the validation status.
        //
        // Exceptions:
        //   System.ArgumentNullException:
        //     The httpContext parameter is null.
        protected virtual HttpValidationStatus OnCacheAuthorization(HttpContextBase httpContext);
    }
}
```

Main differences between those two are:

- `System.Web.Http` version can be used by Web API
- `System.Web.Mvc` version can be used by ASP.NET MVC
- `Http` version use `HttpActionContext` parameter type in OnAuthorization method when `Mvc` version use `AuthorizationContext` type.

I want to access request cookies in `Http` version of `AuthorizeAttribute`. In `Mvc` version it is implemented as follows:

```
public class Foo : AuthorizeAttribute
{
     public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) 
     {
          HttpCookie cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("Bar");    
     }
}
```

Does anybody know how can I do the same with `HttpActionContext`? Is it possible at all? If it's not possible - why it is so?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
public class Foo : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var cookie = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies("Bar").FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly, but close enough ;).

Comment: @Ryan As far as I remember it's all about browsing in a debugger result of GetCookies method executed without any arguments. There should be some arrays and it's relatively straightforward to figure it out how to get the cookies.

Comment: @Ryan - I think the missing piece is this: if for example your cookie has a username=myUserName so you'd need to add a line after what Prasanjit wrote - `string username = cookie.Cookies.Where(c => c.Name == "username").FirstOrDefault().Value;` to extract myUserName

Comment: `var cookie = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies("Bar").FirstOrDefault()?["Bar"];`

Answer (score 8):

```
string sessionId = "";

CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("bar").FirstOrDefault();
if (cookie != null)
{
    sessionId = cookie["bar"].Value;
}
```

Comment: What is a reason that you need to specify "Bar" twice?

Comment: first check indicates whether the required cookie itself is present or not. second code helps in retrieving the value for further processing.

Answer (score 3):

[GetCookies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestheadersextensions.getcookies(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Net.Http.HttpRequestHeadersExtensions.GetCookies%28System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders,System.String%29) returns collection of cookie**S** then you will need to get cookie that you need.

```
public class Foo : AuthorizeAttribute
{

      public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
      {
           var cookies = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies("Bar").FirstOrDefault();

           var cookie = cookies["Bar"];
      }
}
```

Comment: What is a reason that you need to specify "Bar" twice?