# How to get cookies from HttpActionContext on AuthorizeAttribute custom class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cookies

I am validating a token stored on cookies, so I created a class

```
public class VIEWAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
```

then I overrode the OnAuthorization class

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
   var cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("Profile"); //This is working

   if (cookie != null && IsValidToken(cookie["Token"]))
   {
       return;
   }

   HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
}
```

That works fine for MVC Controllers, but when I try to do something similar for web api controller, I am not able to get the cookies from the request.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var foo = actionContext.Request.Headers.Cookies; //that is not working
    if (Authorize(actionContext))
    {
        return;
    }
    HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
}
```

`actionContext.Request.Headers` does not have a method `Cookies`, I also tried with `actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies("Bar")` like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38455135/1762393), but Header does not have that `GetCookies` method.

Any idea?

Comment: You could use `HttpContext.Current`, as I see no way to get to the current context in any other way. For some reason, that `HttpActionContext` does not have access to the actual `HttpRequest`

Comment: What is exactly your issues with the  `actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies` method? This one should do the job

Answer (score 0):

```
string Authentication = string.Empty;
if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Contains("Cookie_Phone"))
{
    Authentication = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Cookie_Phone")?.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide more information on your answer, explaining what was the issue and how your answer solves it.

Answer (score 0):

To use this extension method the namespace `System.Net.Http` is needed.

Also, pay attention on the `GetCookies(string name)` is an extension method that returns any cookie header present in the request that contain a cookie state whose name that matches the specified value. It returns a `CookieHeaderValue` that contains a collection of `CookieValueCollection` instances. So you need extra enumeration to get a `CookieState` by name that contains a value.

Here is the valid code:

```
public async Task AuthenticateAsync(
       HttpAuthenticationContext context, 
       CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var request = context.Request;
    var token = request.Headers
        .GetCookies("token").FirstOrDefault()
        ?.Cookies.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == "token")
        ?.Value;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult(
            "The token is missing.", 
            request);
        return;
    }
    
    var principal = await SomeAuthentication(token);

    if (principal == null)
    {
        context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult(
            "The principal has not been resolved.", 
            request);
        return;
    }

    context.Principal = principal;
}
```